# Yellow Dot Appeared During Modelling, Advice Please?

Tags: modeling

I was following the Polygon Runway Temple tutorial then this yellow dot appeared, ive googled it but as I dont know what its called i have not found an answer, can anyone tell me what it is and how to remove it please? I am pretty sure it wasn't there when I began.

Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have selected an extrude tool:

Press <kbd>T</kbd> to select different tool:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it.

Comment: @IntendedConfusion  Please do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you". Comments are meant for requesting clarification, leaving constructive criticism, or adding relevant but minor additional information – not for socializing. If you want to say "thank you," vote on or accept that person's answer, or simply pay it forward by providing a great answer to someone else's question. https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers